# ASP.net ViewState

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

where is asp.net testing if a viewstate is valid and what happens if it is not valid?

Do I have to validate the ViewState by myself?

Asp.net 3.5

BR
Thanks

Comment: You need to add some detail to this question - type of code you're working on, what you're tried, etc.

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797918.aspx) mentions all the main points

Comment: @ IrishChieftain 
As far as I understand, ViewState is a block of data stored in a hidden filed , which contains the state of your webpage. The browser will send back the ViewState and then at some point Asp.net checks if the ViewState is valid. I want to know if it is done automatically or do I have to enable the validation somehow? And what happens if the validation fails? What will be send back to the user ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where is asp.net testing if a viewstate is valid and what happens if
>   it is not valid?

You'll get an exception if ViewState is invalid.

The ViewState is validated when the page is posted back and it happens before the Page_Load (LoadViewState green box on the pic below) event is raised. [Read here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for more details

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend you reading this excellent article about ViewState and the ASP.NET lifecycle. It opened my eyes and I think it would help you understand how ViewState works. It has a section about validation and security:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Thanks I will go through that aricle :-)